# functors with a morphism lifting property

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory

By analogy to the familiar situation in homotopy theory (i.e., (unique) path lifting in covering spaces), it is natural to consider the following. Let $P:C\to D$ be a functor. Say that $P$ has (unique) morphism lifting if given any $f\colon x \to y$ in $D$ and $y'$ in $C$ with $P(y')=y$, there exists a (unique) $f'\colon x'\to y'$ with $P(f')=f$. In other words, any morphism whose codomain can be lifted, can itself be (uniquely) lifted. One can also use the domain instead of the codomain.

I'm looking for references to this notion, or any useful comment.

Comment: This notion is well-known in algebraic topology, but I forgot the name. It appears in the context of algebraic K-theory, Quillen's Theorems A and B, I think.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg as far as I know Quillen's Theorem A involves a similar notion of liftings but with some stricter conditions (i.e., the lifting being cartesian). If you happen to remember the name, or find a reference, I'd be delighted to know it.

Comment: Isn't this a discrete fibration?

Comment: @ZhenLin yes ! :) the unique lifting property is precisely a discrete fibrations (so thanks already). What is the lifting is not unique?

Comment: I don't know any name for that. Grothendieck (pre)fibrations have an additional condition on the lift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such functors can be shown to exhibit behaviour much like discrete Grothendieck fibrations, but multivalued. Details can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284625540_Metric_constructions_of_topological_invariants).